# How to generate Pascal code from an XML schema in Delphi Prism?

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, delphi-prism

I need to import some XML schemas.
In Delphi, I would use the the **XML Data Binding Wizard** to generate the **Pascal code** from the schemas.
Is there something like that in **Delphi Prism** to avoid writing all this boilerplate code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try xsd.exe from the Microsoft SDK.
/l:Oxygene generates Delphi Prism code.

Comment: Got this error: "Could not find specified code provider type: Chrome"

Comment: Is Prism installed? The command-line version doesn't work. You can try /l:Oxygene. Both works on my computer.

Comment: If you mean Delphi Prism, yes, it is installed (with the VS coming with it). But I don't see how I can launch xsd except from command line?

Comment: I think this error message comes from the xsd-Tool included into the mono-distribution. Make sure you use the one from the Microsoft SDK.